# Integration with outlook calendar

Tags: outlook, office365, kaizala, kaizala-action

I start test kaizala, but i have some doubts about "**Let's Meet**" feature:
When i sent a "**Let's Meet**" it's possible integrate with outlook calendar? 
Many thanks 
Eduardo

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, currently, there is no API to achieve it in Microsoft Kaizala app. I've checked the Kaizala API e.g. [Post a Action in a group for Let's Meet feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/kaizala/connectors/actions_post)
and you can refer to Sample JSON Request for a Let's Meet Action in the article.

However, maybe you could feedback to the Kaizala team with your needs. Please see the following link(the bottom of the article):
[Microsoft Kaizala Developer Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/kaizala/developer-platform)